# .htaccess Redirect 404 Error

Tags: .htaccess

I've been trying to get this right for 1 or 2 hours now, searching for similar problems and trying the solutions. This is probably is one of those thing again where the answer is really obvious.

I am trying to redirect everyone who is accessing *domain.com/title/**whatever*** and *domain.com/title/**anotherpage*** to a PHP script, but it is giving me a 404 error when I try to access the page.

I am using this code in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/plugins/(.*)$ /yourscript.php?plugin=$1 [L]
```

Here is a full copy of my .htaccess file.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.php

#Prevent full listing of files
Options -Indexes 

#Redirect plugins
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/plugins/(.*)$ /foobar.php?plugin=$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>

#Hide .php extension
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>

#compress
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
```

I've tried placing the foobar.php script in both the root folder and in a folder name plugins.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: What is the error message you're getting? A standard 404 or also something like "Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument"? Also note that if I am not mistaken, `ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.php` will point to `domain.com/error/404.php` (is this what you intended?). Please also try to single out the error by (temporarily) removing irrelevant lines in your htaccess.

Comment: @Spooky I am getting a normal 404 error. No "Additionally...". The location for the ErrorDocument is intended and shows my custom error page fine. I have also tried just the first snippet of my code, but it still gave me the error.

Comment: "shows my custom error page fine" - Well then... I think I'm not understanding what your problem/goal is. If it's something to do with `RewriteRule` then I'm backing out as I have no clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like everything's in the right place, but you might want to try removing the leading slash in your regular expression (or at least make it optional):

```
RewriteRule ^/?plugins/(.*)$ /yourscript.php?plugin=$1 [L]
```

In an htaccess file, apache removes the prefix (leading slash) of the URI before it hands it off to the rules in an htaccess file.

---

> domain.com/plugins/**whatever** gets redirected correctly. However, domain.com/**plugins** also gets directed to the script. Instead, I would like to have it so that it directs to a index.php file in a folder name "plugins"

Then you need to change the above rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^/?plugins/(.+)$ /yourscript.php?plugin=$1 [L]
```

(Note the `*` is change to a `+` to match at least 1 character). You probably don't need to add any more rules as long as `index.php` is a valid index, meaning if you just go to `/plugins/` apache will automatically server the index.php file.

Comment: Thanks, this works great. _domain.com/plugins/**whatever**_ gets redirected correctly. However, _domain.com/**plugins**_ also gets directed to the script. Instead, I would like to have it so that it directs to a index.php file in a folder name "plugins".

Comment: Hmm, it still matches domain.com/plugins and redirects it to yourscript.php. I removed the rule and went to the plugins folder and it served me index.php, so it is a valid index and just an htacess rule problem.

Comment: Not sure why that would match, maybe add a condition explicitly? `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/plugins/?$` above the rule